# Retrieving time incorrectly as 1970-01-01 as opposed to format HH:mm

Tags: java, sqlite, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to add a time to `sqlite` database. 
Here is some information before I ask the question:

1. The time field in `sqlite` is of type DateTime.
2. In the bean DTO class, getters and setters correspond to the Date type for time.

So, this is my format for time:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

This is how I submit the information for addition to the database:

```
 edto.setTime(formatter.parse(startHrs.getText() + ":" + startMin.getText()));
```

in sqlite it becomes something like this:

40320000

However, when I want to populate my JTable with data from the database, the time is displayed as `1970-01-01`.I want it to show the actual time rather than this. with other type I handled them like this:

```
private void setDTOField(Field dtoField, BaseDTO dto, ResultSet rs) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IOException, InstantiationException {
        dtoField.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            if (byte[].class.equals(dtoField.getType())) {
                String mimedString = rs.getString(getDBColumnName(dtoField.getName()));
                if (mimedString != null) {
                    byte[] compressedBytes = convertBASE64StringToBytes(mimedString);
                    dtoField.set(dto, compressedBytes);
                }
            } else if (Date.class.equals(dtoField.getType())) {
                dtoField.set(dto, rs.getDate(getDBColumnName(dtoField.getName())));
            }
```

so what Can I do, i'm clueless about the time. the Date was fine, but time I'm not sure. What could be changed? is it easily corrected? maybe in the database it should be string, or in the bean shouldn't be of Date. guys please support me with some solutions.

Comment: java.util.Date stores dates as a milliseconds offset from the Epoch (1970-01-01).  It is not suitable for just storing time of day.  I suspect the same is true of sqllite DateTime.  For this I would use a String or possibly int (number of minutes since midnight).

Comment: Try using [**JodaTime**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It gives you better handling and functionality of date and time values.